# Switching Heroku app to server in other region

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I currently have a Heroku app myapp-us.herokuapp.com on a US based server, while I would like the app to run on an EU based server. But it's not possible within Heroku to change the region of an existing app.

Therefore, within Heroku I've created a second app now with the EU region selected: myapp-eu.herokuapp.com. My idea would be

- 1) add myapp-eu.herokuapp.com as domain to my app
- 2) git push my app to that domain (I'm using git),
- 3) to remove myapp-us.herokuapp.com,
- 4) lastly to rename myapp-eu.herokuapp.com to myapp-us.herokuapp.com (since I've given out that domain name to other people).

So after creating myapp-eu.herokuapp.com on herokuapp.com, I wanted to add this domain within the IDE I work from (step 1): `heroku domains:add myapp-eu.herokuapp.com`. However, this responds with `failed, myapp-eu.herokuapp.com is currently in use by another app`.

What am I doing wrong? Am I also to make git-related changes for step 2?

---

*Update:* I did `git remote rm heroku` to remove the heroku-git connection. Then `heroku git:remote -a myapp-eu` to add the new heroku-git connection.

Next I did `git push heroku master`. This produced the error: `Precompiling assets failed. Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app. [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined). error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myapp-eu.git'`. 
Any idea what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem proofed to be that I hadn't yet added the environment variables for myapp-eu at herokuapp.com. Doing so solved it.